# Import existing git repositories into Gitorious

Tags: ruby, git

I am trying to find out how to import existing git repositories into Gitorious CE. I followed the instructions from http://getgitorious.com/install-gitorious to install the server on a CentOS 6.5 box.

All the google results I can find are from 2010 or 2011. The best I found was a script on http://www.pedro.kiefer.com.br/2011/02/from-cvs-to-git-to-gitorious. However, trying to run their script (after changing the path to "environment.rb") gives the following error:

```
/var/www/gitorious/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:47:in `resolve_hash_connection': database configuration does not specify adapter (ActiveRecord::AdapterNotSpecified)
    from /var/www/gitorious/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:41:in `resolve_string_connection'
    from /var/www/gitorious/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:25:in `spec'
    from /var/www/gitorious/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/connection_adapters/abstract/connection_specification.rb:130:in `establish_connection'
    from /var/www/gitorious/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:88:in `block (2 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
    from /var/www/gitorious/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `instance_eval'
    from /var/www/gitorious/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:36:in `execute_hook'
    from /var/www/gitorious/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:26:in `block in on_load'
    from /var/www/gitorious/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `each'
    from /var/www/gitorious/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activesupport-3.2.19/lib/active_support/lazy_load_hooks.rb:25:in `on_load'
    from /var/www/gitorious/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-3.2.19/lib/active_record/railtie.rb:80:in `block in <class:Railtie>'
    from /var/www/gitorious/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `instance_exec'
    from /var/www/gitorious/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/initializable.rb:30:in `run'
    from /var/www/gitorious/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/initializable.rb:55:in `block in run_initializers'
    from /var/www/gitorious/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `each'
    from /var/www/gitorious/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/initializable.rb:54:in `run_initializers'
    from /var/www/gitorious/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/application.rb:136:in `initialize!'
    from /var/www/gitorious/app/vendor/bundle/ruby/2.0.0/gems/railties-3.2.19/lib/rails/railtie/configurable.rb:30:in `method_missing'
    from /var/www/gitorious/app/config/environment.rb:5:in `<top (required)>'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from /opt/rubies/ruby-2.0.0-p451/lib/ruby/2.0.0/rubygems/core_ext/kernel_require.rb:55:in `require'
    from ../import:10:in `<main>'
```

Ruby is not a language I am familiar with, so it's not easy for me to debug what is wrong.

Comment: I am not familiar with it, but it would seem Gitorious utilises a database and that script is trying to connect to it.  The activerecord gem is complaining it's unable to connect to it. "*database configuration does not specify adapter*"

Comment: Look at your `config/database.yml`.